# Multiple errors while cleaning up old jars

Tags: java, struts, taglib, websphere-8, ibm-rad

I am working on J2EE Application with RAD/WAS 8.5 runtime. I was cleaning up old jars in this very old project and referencing new jars. Everything was working fine, but after a workspace clean and a server restart I started getting these errors.

`com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser logParseErrorMessage Failed to parse Tag Library [/WEB-INF/commontags.tld]: /WEB-INF/commontags.tld`

`com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser logParseErrorMessage Failed to parse Tag Library [/WEB-INF/displaytag.tld]: /WEB-INF/displaytag.tld`

and

`javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Missing configuration resource for path /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml`

I am just not able to figure out if there's a problem with a missing jar or I have conflicting jars in my workspace. I have not changed any of the *.xml files or any code.

Any ideas with what will be the best possible way to debug this issue would be great. Thanks!

***Update:***

[image]

***In web.xml:***

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name></display-name>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
.
.
.    
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>commontags</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/commontags.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/displaytag.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

***I am not sure about newer versions for these jars. Are these covered in struts-taglibs or any other struts jars?!***

[image]

***WebSphere error log:***

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: ‎MyWebProject.‎
WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new session ‎context for application key default_host/testhost
jsp           E com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser logParseErrorMessage Failed to parse Tag Library [/WEB-‎INF/commontags.tld]: /WEB-INF/commontags.tld
jsp           E com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser logParseErrorMessage Failed to parse Tag Library [/WEB-‎INF/displaytag.tld]: /WEB-INF/displaytag.tld
FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on ‎C:\IBM\WebSphere85\AppServer\profiles\testwas85\logs\ffdc\server1_d215675c_13.12.03_16.15.45.25‎‎03351670868379650030.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl 272‎
ActionServlet I org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet initChain Loading chain catalog from ‎wsjar:file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere85/AppServer/profiles/testwas85/installedApps/HJKGFL4Node05Cell/MyEARProject.ear/MyWebProject.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.10.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-‎config.xml
PropertyMessa W org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources loadLocale   Resource ‎org/apache/struts/action/ActionResources_en_US.properties Not Found.‎
PropertyMessa W org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources loadLocale   Resource ‎org/apache/struts/action/ActionResources_en.properties Not Found.‎
ActionServlet E org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet splitAndResolvePaths Missing configuration ‎resource for path /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp commonInitializationFinally SRVE0266E: ‎Error occured while initializing servlets: {0}
                                 javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Missing configuration resource for path /WEB-‎INF/struts-config.xml
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.splitAndResolvePaths(ActionServlet.java:1872)‎
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:683)‎
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:356)‎
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)‎
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:337)‎
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1360)‎
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:606)‎
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:576)‎
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:425)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)‎
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)‎
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)‎
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)‎
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)‎
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1173)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)‎
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:772)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1367)‎
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2172)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)‎
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:11‎‎6)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)‎
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5459)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5585)‎
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1259)‎
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)‎
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)‎
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)‎
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)‎
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:68)‎
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)‎
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)‎
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)‎
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)‎
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)‎
at ‎javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1256)‎
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)‎
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)‎
at ‎javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:125‎‎0)‎
at ‎javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1088)‎
at ‎com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:8‎‎31)‎
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:804)‎
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)‎
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)‎
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.startDeployment(StartDeploymentTask.‎java:247)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.fullAppUpdate(StartDeploymentTask.java:119)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.performTask(StartDeploymentTask.java:107)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor$ExpandApp.expand(AppBinaryProcessor.java:1709)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor.postProcessSynchronousExt(AppBinaryProcessor.java:749)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.postProcess(BLABinaryProcessor.java:590)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.onChangeCompletion(BLABinaryProcessor.java‎:467)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BinaryProcessorWrapper.onChangeCompletion(BinaryProcessorWrapper.java:109)‎
at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.postNotify(FileRepository.java:1924)‎
at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.update(FileRepository.java:1433)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.management.repository.client.LocalConfigRepositoryClient.update(LocalConfigRepositoryClient.java:189)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.update(WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.java:665)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.update(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1998)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.synch(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1946)‎
at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceImpl.synch(WorkSpaceImpl.java:549)‎
at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceImpl.save(ConfigServiceImpl.java:719)‎
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)‎
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)‎
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)‎
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)‎
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:68)‎
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)‎
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)‎
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)‎
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)‎
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)‎
at ‎javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1256)‎
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)‎
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)‎
at ‎javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:125‎‎0)‎
at ‎javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1088)‎
at ‎com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:8‎‎31)‎
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:804)‎
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)‎
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)‎
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)‎
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)‎
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)‎
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)‎
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)‎
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:478)‎
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:312)‎
at ‎com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:65)‎
at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:733)‎
at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:532)‎
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)‎
```

‎

Comment: So does your struts-config.xml reference those tld files? Are they referenced in your web.xml? Which jars got replaced? Among others, did the Struts jars get replaced, and from what version to what version?

Comment: I am referencing tld files in web.xml. There are around 30 jars which I replaced. I have migrated Struts from 1.1 to 1.3. I have added a snapshot of some jars whose new versions I am not sure of, if exists; Atleast not in our Ivy repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folks, here's how I did it.

Open the file causing the trouble, in this case `commontags.tld`, `displaytag.tld` and `struts-config.xml` and make a fake edit i.e `add/delete a line`. And voila! All the errors are mysteriously gone!

**Flashback:** I had to fake edit my `application.xml` earlier when the ***`.war`*** file was not showing up in the WebSphere Enterprise Applications tab on Administrative Console.

`I assume for some reasons the`***`.ear`***`file in my local server was not updated even after re-deploying.`

A better explanation is most welcome! Thanks!

**PS:** I am still getting a `HTTP 404 Not Found` error on deploying the web app but this question is done here.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like an Eclipse/RAD error most likely, then. I'll say that I think I've seen some similar things with my most recent version of RAD. I was going to suggest actually removing the application from the server, restarting the server, then re-adding the application if we ran out of other options.

Answer (score 0):

When you "cleaned up" your jars, did you set them in both the `Java Build Path` and in the `Deployment Assembly`? I find I sometimes change the former and forget that this clears the latter.

Comment: As for my web project, I just replaced the old jars with the new ones in the WEB-INF/lib folder and setup the other jars to be fetched via our Ivy repository.

Comment: Check Deployment Assembly settings. Even replacing jars in WEB-INF/lib *might* have modified that. Plus, do you have the Ivy Eclipse plugin so that you can add Ivy jars to your Deployment Assembly path?

Comment: I did that already. Added snapshot. Could it be that I am referencing some of the common jars from my EAR Project?

Comment: Well, rats. I was hoping it was that simple "gotcha", but it looks like you have all those items covered.